# jquery find and replace last parameter from a url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi first of all I've already looked around but there is nothing that matched what I want to happen, so I'm asking if anyone can help me with this.

I have a URL "/view/album/4/photo/1"
and i want to remove the last parameter and replace it with something.
What i want to do is to find the last "/" and remove the number after it and replace it with a new value.

It's easy with php but i don't know how to do it in jquery since I just started learning it. So I'd really appreciate anyone who can help. :)

By the way this is my code in getting the url:

action = $(form).attr('action'); // "/view/album/4/photo/1"

I don't know what to do with the variable to change the value of the last param

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/hE6MC/

**OR** http://jsfiddle.net/YwG6b/

API: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp

BTW I knw about `:)` http://w3fools.com

**code**

```
url = "/view/album/4/photo/1"
var value = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

alert(value);

url = url.replace(value, 'hulk')
alert("new url => " + url);​
```

**another way**

```
var str = '/view/album/4/photo/1';
var i = str.lastIndexOf('/');
if (i != -1) {
    str = str.substr(0, i) + "/new stuff";
}

alert(str);
​
```

Comment: Meh! I see a pitfall. what if `url = "/view/album/4/photo/4"` ? `:)`

Comment: awesome! thank you so much.this is very helpful and with a demo as well. thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @user949000 no probs! Glad it helped :))

Comment: The _first way_ will fail in some cases. The _another way_ is the way to go!

Answer (score 5):

```
var paths = location.pathname.split('/');
paths[ paths.length-1 ] = 'foo'; // new value
location.pathname = paths.join('/');
```

Comment: This is perfect. Works well minus the regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

Easy and simple: regexp.

```
action = (action.match(/(.*)\d+$/) == null) ? action : (action.match(/(.*)\d+$/)[1]+"2");
```

gives

```
/view/album/4/photo/2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only wants to replace last character you can use `slice` method.

```
$('form').attr('action', function(i, a){
    a.slice(0, -1) + 'number'
})
```